# Interactive line drawing tool

Tags: add-on, vertices, edges

I would like create an add-on that allows me to select a location, add a vertex, select a second location, add a vertex, etc. while adding edges between each. Basically making a line drawing system. Is it possible to use this tool to allow interactive creation of those vertices? If not, is there another way?
[image: This tool]

Comment: CTRL + RIGHT CLICK while a vertex is selected will create a new vertex at click position, connected to the prrevious vertex with an edge

Comment: and bang....learnt something valuable today!! ;) Thanks!

Comment: Just what I was looking for, blender is amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already possible by Shift-A -> Add Single Vert -> then press E to extrude and you get a new vert to move and place.

**Prerequisite**: enable this build-in add-on: [image]